# Deserialise API Response of PlayWright using Java

Tags: java, api, deserialization, playwright, playwright-java

I am exploring playwright for automating api tests and I am unable to deserialise APIResponse of playwright to a POJO using java. I used to do this with rest assured using following code:

```
        PetStoreModel petStoreModel =  response.as(PetStoreModel.class);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this with the help of ObjectMapper.

```
APIResponse response = getPetStoreResponse();
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
PetStoreModel petStoreModel = objectMapper.readValue(response.text(),PetModel.class);
```